# Use of uninitialized value in division (/) at test.pl line 45

Tags: perl

I've got such error when I'm trying to run my perl script for snmp check:

```
Use of uninitialized value in division (/) at test.pl line 45.
Use of uninitialized value in division (/) at test.pl line 46.
Illegal division by zero at test.pl line 47.
```

There is my script:

```
     #!/usr/bin/perl

        use strict;
        use warnings;
        use Getopt::Long;
        use Net::SNMP;

        my $mem_used = "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.48.1.1.1.5";
        my $mem_free = "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.48.1.1.1.6";
        my $mem_used_asr = "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.221.1.1.1.1.18.7000.1";
        my $mem_free_asr = "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.221.1.1.1.1.20.7000.1";
        my $dev_check = "1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.13.1";

        my ($session,$error);

        ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(
                -hostname  => "some_IP_address",
                -version   => 2,
                -community => "some_community",
                -port      => 161,
                -timeout   => 15
                 );

        my @oidlists = ($dev_check);

        my $resultat = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => \@oidlists);

        $session->close;

        $resultat = "@{[%${resultat}]}";

        print $resultat;

        if ($resultat =~ /some_string/) {

                my @oidlist = ($_mem_used_asr, $_mem_free_asr);

  43.              my $result = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => \@oidlist);
                  or warn $session->error;
                   $session->close;
                  print Dumper $result;
                        $session->close;

                my @load = undef;

      45.              $load[0]=int($$result{$mem_used_asr}/1024/1024);
      46.              $load[1]=int($$result{$mem_free_asr}/1024/1024);
      47.              $load[2]=int($load[0]/($load[0]+$load[1])*100);

                print "Memory : used = $load[0] MB, free = $load[1] MB, utilization = $load[2] % :";

        } else {

                my @oidlist = ($_mem_used, $_mem_free);
                my $result = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => \@oidlist);
                        $session->close;

                my @load = undef;

                    $load[0]=int($$result{$mem_used}/1024/1024);
                    $load[1]=int($$result{$mem_free}/1024/1024);
                    $load[2]=int($load[0]/($load[0]+$load[1])*100);

                print "Memory : used = $load[0] MB, free = $load[1] MB, utilization = $load[2] % :";
        }

        exit;
```

That's what I've get from print Dumper $result: $VAR1 = undef;

But if I will delete if condition, the snmp request works properly. Could you please help me? (Yeah, it quite newbie perl script, as I'm not good in it)

For example, such code is working fine:

```
my @oidlist = ($mem_used_asr, $mem_free_asr);

        my $result = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => \@oidlist);

        $session->close;
        print $result;
        my @load = undef;

        $load[0]=int($$result{$mem_used_asr}/1024/1024);
                $load[1]=int($$result{$mem_free_asr}/1024/1024);
                $load[2]=int($load[0]/($load[0]+$load[1])*100);

                print "Memory : used = $load[0] MB, free = $load[1] MB, utilization = $load[2] % :";

exit;
```

Comment: Print $$result{$mem_used_asr} & $$result{$mem_free_asr} you'll know why!!

Comment: Use of uninitialized value in bitwise and (&) at test.pl line 50.
Use of uninitialized value in bitwise and (&) at test.pl line 50.

Comment: _Use of uninitialized value_ in not an error, its warning which means there is no value initialize to those variables.

Comment: But $result is receiving valure from the snmp request.

Comment: Then it has to be `$mem_used_asr`.

Comment: As I wrote, this is only a part of code, so all variables like $mem_used_asr, $mem_free_asr have values and defined.

Comment: Clearly they aren't, because otherwise you wouldn't get an error. Can I suggest adding in `use Data::Dumper` and `print Dumper $result` just before that line?

Comment: How are you assigning value to the key `$mem_used_asr`? Could there be newlines, or other things that is messing with your keys. They must be exact. `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $mem_used_asr` to see exactly if you have what you think you have.

Comment: Also, when there is ever a case of you thinking "Perl is saying this value is undefined, but I KNOW it isn't." then always keep in mind that Perl is *never* wrong, it is you that is wrong. Always.

Comment: use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use Net::SNMP;

my $mem_used = "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.48.1.1.1.5";
my $mem_free = "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.48.1.1.1.6";
my $mem_used_asr = "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.221.1.1.1.1.18.7000.1";
my $mem_free_asr = "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.221.1.1.1.1.20.7000.1";
my $dev_check = "1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.13.1";

Comment: This is how I've assigned values for those keys. Also, Example script is working properly with those values and shows correct result. So, as I think, the reason of this issue is not in OID values.

to TLP - I know that Perl is not wrong in my case, that's why I've created a question here, to see, where is my mistake

Comment: Please don't post long strings of code in comments like that. Edit your question to add this information.

Comment: @sem1993 Use the arrow syntax instead `$result->{$mem_used_asr}`. See if that helps.

Comment: @TLP: That seems rather like clutching at straws :-)

Comment: "That's what I've get from print Dumper $result: `$VAR1 = undef;`" Well that pretty much explains all the other problems then :-)

Comment: From the documentation for `get_request()` - " In either mode, the undefined value is returned when an error has occurred. The `error()` method may be used to determine the cause of the failure."

Comment: @DaveCross Thank you! That was really helpfull

Comment: @DaveCross Well, if it is returning some sort of overloaded or otherwise strange object, using the (IMO) more obscure syntax might not work as intended. :) It would be a typical symptom for a `$foo = something; $foo is now nothing; $foo is now something` kind of problem.

Comment: So, it's returning: The Transport Domain object is not defined at test.pl line 43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting errors, you're getting warnings.

This means that both `$$result{$mem_used}` and `$$result{$mem_free}` are undefined. That means that both `$load[0]` and `$load[1]` will be undefined and that leads to your third error.

So we need to take a closer look at `$result` to see what is going on  there. We get `$result` from this line of code:

```
my $result = $session->get_request(@oidlist);
```

It's hard to know for sure as we don't know for sure what type of object `$session` is. You mention "snmp", so let's guess that it's a [Net::SNMP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMP) object. That class has a [get_request()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMP#get_request---send-a-SNMP-get-request-to-the-remote-agent) method which returns a hash reference - so it's likely my guess is a good one (but as note for the future - asking people who are helping you debug problems to make guesses like this isn't very polite).

As an aside here, the `$$result{$mem_used}` syntax that you're using here is pretty non-standard. Most Perl programmers would write that at `$result->{$mem_used}`.

If `$result->{$mem_used}` is undefined, then it means one of two things. Either the key `$mem_used` exists and the associated value is `undef`. Or the key just doesn't exist in the hash. You can use the `exists` function to check which of these two possibilities is the case here.

I know little about SNMP, but it seems to be that you're using the `-varbindlist` argument correctly, so I don't think I can be much more help in tracking down the problem. I would suggest using something like [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) to display the contents of `$result` as soon as you get it - perhaps that will give you a better idea of what is going on here.

**Update:** Hang on. It looks like I was wrong when I said that you were using `-varbindlist` correctly. You have two calls to `get_request()`.

```
my $result = $session->get_request(@oidlist);
$session->get_request(-varbindlist => \@oidlist);
```

The second of those calls has the correct `-varbindlist` parameter. The first of them (and that's the one that you use the result from) is incorrect.

I bet that if you combine those two lines into:

```
my $result = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => \@oidlist);
```

then it will work.

**Update 2:** From an update to your question, I see that you're getting `undef` back from your call to `get_request()`. The documentation says:

> In either mode, the undefined value is returned when an error has
>   occurred. The error() method may be used to determine the cause of
>   the failure.

So your next steps seem pretty obvious.

```
my $result = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => \@oidlist)
  or warn $session->error.
```

Comment: my $result = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => \@oidlist);
check my script in question, I've updated it

Comment: And what do you get from using Data::Dumper to print `$result` (put the information in the question, not a comment).